# on hover on list box to show a text box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a access `listbox` that has 2 columns and the column width is...2";0" so the second one is hidden.

I know I can do a `controltip` to display a single line but the values in the 2nd column are quite long.  They are descriptions of what is in column 1.

How can one display a `textbox` with the value in the 2nd column when hovered over a specific item in the list box?

Answer (score 0):

To access different columns in a listbox you can use this:

```
Me.ListBox1.Column(0)
```

The 0 being the first column, simply adjust to what column you want to show. So if you are doing this in VBA code you would use the OnUpdate event and end up with something like this:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Me.ListBox1.ControlTipText = Me.ListBox1.Column(0)
End Sub
```

Take note that the field you want the Controltip text to show up for must be selected.  I don't believe there is any way to change that shows up in the control tip text without implicitly selecting a row in the listbox.